# Conditional execution of a Class

Tags: c++, function-pointers, new-operator, conditional-statements

I am newbie to C++ programming.

Below is my code having two classes, `class 1` and `class 2` which does some calculations based on the values from the main function sent through the object pointers  `myclass1` and  `myclass2`.The code works fine but now I need to make a change, that is only when the function `calc` of `class1` returns true value, the `class2` and its member function `computation` should get its value `x` from main function and algorithm runs. i.e if class1 returns true, class 2 runs else No.

It would be grateful if someone could hint me a idea and say how to proceed with it.

Thanks in advance

**Code**

**class1.h**

```
class class1
{
public:
    class1()
    {
    };
    ~class1()
    {
    };

    bool calc(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    if (some condition){ // returns true or false based on some condition
    result=true;
    }
    else{
    result=false;
    }

    return result;
    };
```

**class2.h**

```
class class2
{
public:
    class2()
    {
    };
    ~class2()
    {
    };

    int computation (int x)
    {
    do some calculations
    result=1;
    }
    return result;
    };
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])

class1* myclass1 = new class1();
class2* myclass2 = new class2();

int x=0.5, y=0.7, z=0.9;


int result1 = myclass1->calc(x,y,z);

int result2 = myclass2-> computation(x); // should be assigned or activated only when result1 is true.

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid useless new

Comment: I don't want to come off as rude, but I think you need to go over the basics of c++ control flow again.

Comment: You understand `if` because you used in class1::clc(). Use something similar in main() also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int result = 0;
if(myclass1->calc(x,y,z))
   result = myclass2->computation(x);
```

Note that with `Class1`, you're assigning a `bool` to an `int` - make sure you have proper type assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple if:

```
bool result1 = myclass1->calc(x,y,z);
int result2 = -1; // -1 means not computed in this case

if(result1){
  result2 = myclass2-> computation(x); // should be assigned or activated only when result1 is true.
}
```

Comment: `myclass1->calc(x,y,z);` actually returns a `bool` not a _result_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are right, i just copy-pasted his code. Fixed now.